# Prompt_git_and_status error

Tags: macos, git, terminal

Something strange happened to my git and terminal. My terminal shows command not found error after every execution of commands under the root. Another user's terminals are OK.

**sh: prompt_git_and_status: command not found**

I am running  Mac OS x 10.10.3, git version 2.4.3
Kernel: 
Darwin 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Where can be a problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you type `git --version`

Comment: root@momo : /Users/momo git --version
git version 2.4.3
sh: prompt_git_and_status: command not found

Comment: Seems weird - uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Does the same happen with other installed apps or commands?

Comment: locoboy: I have tried reinstall the git but still getting the error.

Comment: Nick Volynkin: Nope, I have not noticed the same things.

Comment: Sounds like something modified the root user's shell to run this (missing) command when printing the prompt. You might want to check your PS1 variable (export PS1) to make sure and, if it was modified, fix the root user's .profile, .bash_profile, or similar files.